# Can Skylander Giants be used on the PS4 Swap Force?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, skylanders-swap-force, skylanders-giants

My daughter wants one of the Giant figures after playing on a friends Wii - Before I buy any I wanted to check if they will work on the Swap Force starter pack for the Ps4 - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**They can,** though they play a more minimal role in Swap Force unlike Giants. Unlike regular Swap Force figures, Giants can also be used to open Giant Chests.

*Source: [IGN Wiki](http://m.uk.ign.com/wikis/skylanders-swap-force/Giant)*

Comment: Thanks that's a great help, I've a lot to learn regarding Skylanders before Christmas

Comment: @Lisa No problem. If it helped you, please feel free to upvote my answer and mark it as the accepted one.